# Проблема с ZTE MF 667 модемом

Tags: ubuntu, linux

Доброго всем времени. Пытаюсь выйти с интернет с помощью модема через minicom. Прочел [статью](http://hdbor.ru/ubuntu/115-kak-usb-modem-zte-podruzhit-ubuntu-12-04-04.html) , как перевести модем в режим последовательного порта. Но возникла проблема - ось не отображает модем как /dev/ttyUSB*. Резултат lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 19d2:1403 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Я уже изъял модем как CD-ROM, но все равно не помогает. Что делать?

Comment: Как у модема в этом режиме появляется сетевой интерфейс? У меня как у автора, но нет сетевого интерфейса от модема, по этому подключить его не могу, система ubuntu server 16.04 lts x64.

Answer (score 1):

если задача состоит в использовании устройства для доступа в интернет, а не в желании поработать с последовательным портом, то я бы порекомендовал оставить его в текущем режиме (*rndis*) или, если интернет недоступен, то переключить в близкородственный режим — *cdc*.

в обоих этих режимах устройство «представляется» системе как сетевая карта, через которую можно по протоколу *dhcp* получить сетевые настройки и, благодаря им, доступ в интернет.

для переключения между этими режимами надо в браузере перейти на один из указанных адресов.

переключиться в режим *cdc*:

```
http://192.168.0.1/goform/goform_set_cmd_process?goformId=USB_MODE_SWITCH&usb_mode=5
```

переключиться в режим *rndis*:

```
http://192.168.0.1/goform/goform_set_cmd_process?goformId=USB_MODE_SWITCH&usb_mode=3
```

после переключения, скорее всего, потребуется отключить и снова подключить устройство.

---

больше подробностей — [по ссылке](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/linux-hardware/11257454).